# Cant change app.css with adminlte in laravel project

Tags: php, css, laravel, sass, adminlte

After i run npm run watch, my app.css in public folder changes. I included link to that stylesheet inside my master blade of adminlte in laravel but nothing changes. When i open the mywebsite.test/portal/css/app.css it is not same as the file in my public directory.

I tried including my public app.css files in a few places but nothing helps. I included it like this

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

when i write something like this

```
#logotest {
  color: red !important;
  padding: 150px;
}
```

iside my app.scss it showes after compiling in css/app.css, but in my html

```
<link href="http://mywebsite.test/portal/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

there is no trace of my changes

Answer (score 0):

make sure `APP_URL` in you `.env`  does not contain /portal because `asset()` will build from `APP_URL`.

after committing changes to .env run `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: portal is actualy my laravel project. my website is some wordpress and portal part is like a customized admin panel.

Comment: other thing is u must access your laravel index.php from the public folder, did you modify server.php outside public folder to become index.php?

Comment: like this ```require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```  cant find my index.php